# Check if string starts with given string

Tags: perl

I am trying to check if message after "5:16:51:209|INFO| " starts with "Marker". I need to add string "|ICD" after timstamp.

input is :" 05:16:51:209|INFO|Markerprocedure Magnet "

I tried this regex, but its not working. Please help me to get it correct.

```
if ( $lines[$i] =~ m/(\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{3})|(\w+)|^Marker/)
{

  $lines[$i] =~ s/(\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{3})(.*)/$1|ICD$2/ ;

}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
I am trying to check if message after "5:16:51:209|INFO| " starts with "Marker"
```

What it seems to me you're trying to check is whether `Marker` *immediately  follows* `5:16:51:209|INFO|` so it isn't correct to use the `^` regex character because that checks to see whether the start of the string occurs in that position (which, of course, it doesn't).  So remove the `^` character and Perl will check whether `Marker` immediately follows.

Also, you need to escape the `|` characters like this: `\|` to prevent it being treated as an alternation command in the regex.  Then you can do the test and replace in a single substitution command:

```
if ( $lines[$i] =~ s/(\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{3})(\|\w+\|Marker)/$1|ICD$2/ )
{
    # Line contained "Marker" and "|ICD" inserted
}
```

Example:

```
$ echo '15:16:51:209|INFO|Marker blah' | perl -ple 's/(\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{3})(\|\w+\|Marker)/$1|ICD$2/'
```

Output is:

```
15:16:51:209|ICD|INFO|Marker blah
```

**Edit**: @Prix has pointed out in the comments that if the timestamp is meant to appear at the start of the string, then the `^` start-marker should be at the start of the regex to prevent accidental matches in other parts of the string (and for performance):

```
 s/^(\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{3})(\|\w+\|Marker)/$1|ICD$2/
   ↑
   Use ^ here to anchor the search to the beginning of the string.
```

Comment: Actually it is correct to use `^` however he is using it at the wrong place it should be at the begin `/^` as he may not want to find something else that may match the timestamp like in the middle of the string.

Comment: OP never says that the timestamp must be at the start of the string so on that basis, there should be no `^`. But I agree that it is likely that in practice, the match should only occur at the start of the string so I will edit my answer.

Comment: Yes that is correct but I am basing myself on the sample input he provided which does start with the timestamp regardless hope the OP will clear that out. Also according to his sample string there is also an space before the initial number.

Comment: Well if there is a space at the start of the string, then I will leave it to OP to figure out what should be done to the regex to account for it.  Since it's a side-issue not related to the main purpose of the question, I feel that it just over-eggs the answer to respond in such detail.